# Merge a TextureArray with many image files in OpenGLES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

I downloaded an obj file then with a perl script, i generated normals,textures and vertices into a file then copied png files of object into raw directory. If i use an object with only one png file, i can display it. If i try to display an object with many png texture files, i can only use one part of them.

e.g:(whole body textured with face texture)

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bodyMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.body);
Bitmap faceMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.face);
```

My texture array does not have any splitter, so it doesn't know which texture file is appropriate for given position.

What is the proper solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a texture atlas (requires changing the UV coordinates on the model)

or separate the model so each part can have it's own texture (requires multiple draw calls per model)